# $A \preceq MI_{d\times d}$ if and only if the eigenvalues of A are at most M

Tags: matrices, data-analysis

Let $A \in R^{d\times d}$ be a symmetric matrix. Show that $A \preceq MI_{d\times d}$ if and only if the eigenvalues of A are at most M. Similarly, $mI_{d\times d} \preceq A$ if and only if the eigenvalues of A are at least m.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Just do diagonalization to see since every symmetric matrix can be diagonalized.

Comment: @stephenkk Can you explain? I don't understand at all.